# recording setup for field studies

Tags: usability-testing, video

Wondering if anyone here might have some advice: We're going to be undertaking onsite field usability studies for the first time over the next year, and I'm wondering about techniques / equipment / software for recording such sessions.

For user tests we run in-house, we use Morae to capture screen and face video and audio. Possibilities we've thought of for onsite visits are:

1. Video camera with tripod
2. Getting client buy-in to install
   something like GoToMeeting on their machines and record a session
   with it.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have good experiences with recording the sessions using e.g. Camstudio http://camstudio.org/.

Recording the face using a built-in (or external) camera is a very good idea- one can learn quite a lot about the emotions from facial expressions.

I may be considered quite "old-school" but my favorite usability recording technology is called pencil & paper combined with "think-aloud method". It's very often the easiest and most efficient method to capture all the important findings. The advantage of this method is that you don't need to replay any footage, just figure out how to transform the notes into a readable report :)

Depending on how advanced your usability tests are going to be you might consider investing into more specialized equipment for eye-tracking (e.g. Tobii).